# Android: Getting journey duration as per live traffic

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

I wanted to show journey duration to a particular location with live traffic and without traffic. How can this be achieved in an android app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use [Google Maps Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro)